# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter throws a null object

Tags: java, android

My app crashes right away after signin and it gives a null object on

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(Category.class, R.layout.menu_item, MenuViewHolder.class, category)
```

Can someone help or have any better idea?

```
private void LoadMenu(){
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(Category.class, R.layout.menu_item, MenuViewHolder.class, category) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MenuViewHolder viewHolder, Category model, int position) {
                viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.imageView);
                final Category clickItem = model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        //Get CategoryId and send to new Activity
                        Intent foodList = new Intent(Home.this, FoodList.class);
                        //Because Category is key, so we just get the key of this item
                        foodList.putExtra("CategoryId", adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        startActivity(foodList);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

this is the full stacktrace error that crashes my app, I dont know why, Iv'e initiated the FireDatabase and set the database reference to "Category" which is in my firedatabase

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fahad.foodie, PID: 4287
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.fahad.foodie.Home$2.populateViewHolder(Home.java:88)
        at com.fahad.foodie.Home$2.populateViewHolder(Home.java:85)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:184)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1888)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:407)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:693)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Comment: Done sir, sorry I took so long I had no internet for two days..... anyway I've added the stacktrace, could take a look at it? Thanks!

Comment: Please add your  MenuViewHolder.java and the  menu_item.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your textview is not properly defined.

`viewHolder.txtMenuName` is NULL as per the logcat messages.

Please define it properly at your MenuViewHolder like below,

```
 public MenuViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtMenuName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
        imageMenu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

You have to ensure the `txtMenuName` is properly mapped to the textview id(for example   `android:id="@+id/menu_name"`) in the `menu_item.xml`.

Comment: then please mark it as resolved. Answer accepted.